# Why Magento admin panel is often called backend?

Tags: admin-panel

Back-end is a server side code and not admin part of a front-end, we all nkow this.
Then why it keeps been called backend?

Answer (score 1):

I guess because admin users have higher access to functionality that enables them to change front-end content and even how it behaves e.g VAT amount, restrictions to common user types, new carousels, new CMS content etc.

This means admin users have more access to lower levels of abstraction, which common users don't and maybe because the admin manage area is still not visible or accessible to the common user.